# Upgrade the eclipse plugin from 3.8 to 4.25, with unlimited calls to the paintControl method in PaintListener

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am upgrading the version of eclipse plugin from 3.8 to 4.25 and found that the paintControl method in the PaintListener I have been using before triggers infinitely, even if I do not have any UI operations.I don't know if this is due to the upgrade or an issue with my own code. Have any others experienced a similar situation, and how did you resolve it?

```java
@Override
public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
    boolean preAdvanced = e.gc.getAdvanced();
    e.gc.setAdvanced(true);
    e.gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
    loadBinningWidgets(e.gc, new Rectangle(e.x, e.y, e.width, e.height));
    e.gc.setAdvanced(preAdvanced);
}
```

```java
private void loadBinningWidgets(GC gc, final Rectangle area) {
    /*List<CellData> list = layout.getDisplayCellList(area.x, area.y, area.width,
            area.height, siteNode.getAvalibleSite());*/

    List<Integer> showSiteNo = siteNode.getShowSiteNo();
    List<CellData> list = null;
    if(showSiteNo == null){
        list = layout.getDisplayCellList(area.x, area.y, area.width,
                area.height, siteNode.getAvalibleSite());

    }else{
        list = layout.getDisplayCellList(area.x, area.y, area.width,
                area.height, listToInt(showSiteNo));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        CellData cellData = list.get(i);
        widgetList.get(cellData.getIndex()).setCellData(cellData);
        widgetList.get(cellData.getIndex()).redraw(gc);
    }
}
```

I think this method should only be called when there is a change in the UI

Comment: That is a huge jump from a release which is 11 years and 27 releases old to one which is already 1 year and 4 releases old. There were major changes between release 3 and 4. That said I wouldn't really expect problems in a paint listener unless you are doing something invalid in the painting. But you are really going to have to show more details for us to stand any chance of diagnosing the problem.

Comment: What greg-449 says. See also [Plug-in Migration Guide](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/nav/2_3_5).

Comment: Hello, greg-449. I'm glad you're here to help me solve this issue again. This upgrade is indeed significant and has brought many unexpected changes to our code. The original code is now unable to run correctly. I will paste a portion of the code snippet next

Comment: There is far too much undefined in that code to really help. But I would say that code in `paintControl` should only be doing the painting - that `loadBinningWidgets` method looks like it is doing things unrelated to actual painting and should be done somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still feel that it may not be related to the internal method. However, I will try extracting the method and see.

Comment: I found that I set a font variable for the buttons on the interface in the loadBinningWidgets method. This setting will cause the paintControl method to be retriggered, which may be the reason why paintControl executes infinitely.